# Open graph publishing returns "internal server error 500"

Tags: facebook-opengraph, publishing

I want to post a dynamically created action, like in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/:

```
  <?php
`function curPageURL() {`
 `$pageURL = 'http://';`
` if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {` 
 `$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {`
 `$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }` 
 `return $pageURL;
}
?>`

`<html>`<html>
  `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['fb:app_id']);?>">`
   `<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo strip_tags(curPageURL());?>">
      <meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:type']);?>">
      <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:title']);?>">
      <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:image']);?>">
      <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['og:description']);?>">
      <title>Product Name</title>
  </head>`   
  `<body>
      <?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['body']);?>
    </body>
</html>`
```

facebook Object debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) returns that my object is Ok, but when I try to post it through my iOS-app I get a response "internal server error 500"

```
object url:
`http://wl.uasoft.net/wishobject.php?fb:app_id=437320636331183&og:type=mytestbiaka:wish&og:title=wishik&og:description=MyTestBiaka%20app&og:image=http%3A%2F%2Fsilkdream.ru/pict/mult-pict.narod.ru276_small.jpg&body=Wish`

request to fb:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/mytestbiaka:add?wish=http://wl.uasoft.net/wishobject.php?fb:app_id=437320636331183&og:type=mytestbiaka:wish&og:title=wishik&og:description=MyTestBiaka%20app&og:image=http%3A%2F%2Fsilkdream.ru/pict/mult-pict.narod.ru276_small.jpg&body=Wish&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

`

Does anybody get such an error?

Comment: same here... Also following the issue over here but no luck yet: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/569135469770489/

Comment: Any solution to this? We've contacted facebook support about it, but haven't heard back yet.